# Reloading Express Sub-Apps Without Restarting App

Tags: node.js, express

My boss just made an executive decision to run our website as one giant Express app, so I'm stuck trying to work out a usable setup given our situation. We have lots of little Express apps (browser games, interactive RPG character sheets, database viewers, etc.) which are completely separate projects with their own Git repositories and `app.js` files, and we need to be able to push frequent updates to these apps without reloading the entire server and disconnecting users on the rest of the apps. My current plan is to have an 'apps' folder and have a post-commit script to clone each repo to its own subfolder.

The next step is where I'm stuck. I can clear the `require` cache, loop through the apps folder, and `require()` apps when the filesystem detects a change, but that won't remove any mounted routes or middleware. I have no control over the subapps, so I can't manually name and remove each route. Is there any way to accomplish this type of setup with Express?

Comment: Stack Overflow has an excellent careers site in which you can probably find a company with a boss that doesn't make "executive decisions" like this one. This use case is unsupported in NodeJS, it was never built with it in mind and to be fair it's quite a complicated one - for what it's worth while this is possible in some other languages (like Java) it's super easy to get prone and leak memory and state. The only language I've seen do it right is Erlang, lol. I strongly suggest you _don't_ run the website as one giant express app, if you do use child processes for the sub-apps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution I was looking for proved to be effectively impossible given how Express was designed. We ended up setting up a proxy server via `http-proxy` and serving each individual app at its own subdomain, which enabled the hot-reloading we wanted but forced us to find alternative solutions for cross-app communication.